# Angular i18n choosing the best module

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I have been reading about i18n in angular and I have decided to use angular-translate.
But would like to know if I am wrong with my selection.
My site is building from scratch.

Also would appreciate which you consider is the best way to organize the translations.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is basically no way to know. There are also other sensible modules, i.e. [angular-localization](http://doshprompt.github.io/angular-localization/), but... OK, angular-localization advertises itself as being more "Angular way", but by simply analyzing GitHub I am not that convinced (in terms of pure popularity).
That is, angular-translate is the most popular module for providing translations, which equates to widespread adoption - it is probably the least likely to fail.
On the other hand, I can least i18n deficiencies in angular-translate, but in most cases it is good enough.

Now, translations are only the part of the equation. The other part is a support for formatting numbers, dates, currency units, percentages, units of measurements and locale-aware collation (comparison and sorting). To some extent you can use Agnular's built-in "localization" (I have no idea why they call it that way), but you need to combine it with dynamic loading of locales. For that you need something like [Angular Dynamic Locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/), which is a kind of ugly workaround, but it works.

For other parts, you may be forced to switch to [JavaScript built-in support for i18n](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) or even write your own if you want premium support.