# Internationalization on percentage formatting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, locale

How do we do number formatting for location of percentage sign (%) in angular?
For currency, angular has i18n that supports internationalization based on the currency symbol. How about %?
For example, in Turkish, % is put on left side (before the number) instead of on the right side.

Is there a framework from angular to do this?

Comment: Check out this question for a lot of discussion around this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071152/angular-i18n-choosing-the-best-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. Javascript has a built in function for this. I ended up using their functionality and it works perfectly fine https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl.

Hope this helps others.